How to determine if a class is generic via reflection in Kotlin
Suppose we have the following class:
  data class KeyValuePair<T : Any>(
      val key: String,
      val value: T
  )

If we reflect against the following instance of this class: KeyValuePair("color", "amber"), the first property is of course kotlin.String, but the second property has a type name of T. Is there a programmatic way to determine the this KProperty1 is generic? Except for hacks such as "class name does not contain dots".

You can get the type of a property using:
val props = KeyValuePair::class.declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == "value" }
val returnType = props.returnType

This will give you back an instance of KType that represents T. However, there could potentially be a class T defined somewhere and you wouldn't know if T is the generic type or an actual class. Moreover, the generic type could have any name.
Given that the T in the member property is the same T defined as the generic type for the class, I think one way of answering your question would involve:

extracting the list of generic types (aka type parameters) of the class
checking if the return type of the property belongs to that list

Example:
fun main() {
    val classTypeParams = KeyValuePair::class.typeParameters

    KeyValuePair::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach { prop ->
        val returnType = prop.returnType
        println("${prop.name} -> ${returnType.classifier in classTypeParams}")
    }
}

which prints:
key -> false
value -> true

Things became a bit more complex if you want to do the same for functions because:

functions have input and output types, so you need to look in 2 places-
functions can defined their own generic type (e.g. fun <T> foo(): T)

If you want to find out the actual type of T at runtime (e.g. that T is actually a String in your example), you can't do it because of type erasure – you could use reified parameters in inline functions, but even then I don't think you could get what T is at runtime
EDIT:
actually you can get the runtime type of a reified type parameter:
object Foo {
    inline fun <reified T: Any> foo(obj: T) {
        println(obj::class)
    }
}

class MyClass

fun main() {
    Foo.foo("some string") // prints kotlin.String
    Foo.foo(123) // prints kotlin.Int
    Foo.foo(MyClass()) // prints MyClass
}


it works, thanks a lot

please check @broot's answer below as well, as I think their approach is better/easier

We just need to check what is the type of the property and specifically, what's its classifier:
prop.returnType.classifier

classifier is of type: KClassifier and possible subtypes are (among others) KClass and KTypeParameter. At this point this is rather straightforward - we just need to check if classifier is a KTypeParameter:
fun main() {
    val obj = KeyValuePair("color", "amber")
    println(obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.single { it.name == "key" }.isGeneric) // false
    println(obj::class.declaredMemberProperties.single { it.name == "value" }.isGeneric) // true
}

val KProperty<*>.isGeneric get() = returnType.classifier is KTypeParameter

